# UV unwarping stretch

Tags: modeling, uv, uv-image-editor

I am trying to make a shoe model but I have a problem with materials. how ever I unwarp it, it gave me stretch in some places from the map. please, take a look on my project file and try to find the problem.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your material isn't using the UV map, but generated coordinates. Try changing the following in your Material Nodes:

[image]

(I can't test the change as your attached blend file doesn't include your texture)

Comment: What a quick answer! I tested it and worked as it should. Thanks for help @Nicola appreciate that.